# Beads of blocked water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, everyday-life, water, surface-tension

When you let a tap run at a small flow (e.g. 5ml/s), and block the straight flow with your finger, beads form, almost like conjoined drops.  Is there a good explanation for this?

P.S. It may seem like a very noob question,  but I haven't done anything like this before.

Comment: See also [standing waves on a cylindrical jet](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225144).

Comment: @simplest_mathematics Could not get what you wanted to say. A picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the surface area of the tap in contact with the water is bigger therefore each droplet can support more mass creating bigger droplets, the area of the water in contact with the finger is smaller meaning smaller droplets but the flow rate  stays the same so the drops must come faster, sorry i cant give you any maths but that's the basis of it i think