# Oscillating waves on a water stream

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, water, oscillators

I observed something which I've never seen before. We left the tap open and the water stream was flowing in a particular pattern. When we placed a beaker under the water stream, the pattern disappeared. And the pattern itself was oscillating.

Here's the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zX6kjRsKHnk&feature=youtu.be).

Below the the photos of the effect.

[image: No beaker. Pattern observed.]
[image: Beaker placed below. No pattern.]

I saw something like this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225144/standing-waves-on-a-cylindrical-jet/308898#308898). But I'm not certain if it's the same. Is the pattern a standing wave? If yes, is it sound? And why does the pattern disappear when we place a beaker under it? In the later part of the video, you can see that the pattern itself is oscillating. Why is that happening?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh_instability#Theory I don't think this is _definitively_ the cause, but seems to be the most reasonable culprit from similar questions in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [standing waves on a cylindrical jet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225144/standing-waves-on-a-cylindrical-jet)

Comment: @sammy gerbil I asked so many different questions in this one. The previous one looks similar but my question is about why that pattern is oscillating and why the pattern disappears when we place some other object under the stream.

Comment: See also [Patterns in laminar flow of tap water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176410). ... The pattern does not disappear - it moves down. ... Yes, the oscillation is not explained in other questions, so I will retract my vote to close.