# Perturbations on a fluid thread and hydrodynamic instability

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, stress-strain

I know that due to fluid instability there are some perturbations ( picture below )

[image]

after all of these, my question is the reason of existence of these perturbations.
Why exactly they appear? **Shear stress** or **capillary pressure** ?

if the parameters I mentioned are in play please explain me the effect of each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface wave formed in a Rayleigh-Taylor instability is caused mainly by surface tension. Like i mentioned before, a liquid tends to minimize its surface area and $n$ droplets of volume $V/n$ have more surface area than a liquid column of volume $V$.
Initially, the film is uniform and surface tension will minimize the area by starting to form waves. The surface tension is related to the capillary pressure.

**Old (slightly irrelevant) answer**:
*When i wrote this answer i was considering a different type of pertubation than the ones you meant*

Pertubations are part of any real system caused by asymmetries in the system, or changes in air pressure, or someone walking by or a train speeding by, etc. etc.

A perfectly undisturbed symmetric system as you describe in your first picture is very difficult to obtain experimentally. Such a system is therefore a purely theoretical situation.

An example of the influence of pertubations is in determining the transition from the laminar to the turbulent regime in a channel flow. Generally, we say this occurs at $\mathrm{Re}\approx2000$ but notice the approximation sign; due to pertubations caused by external factors, the transition may occur one day at $\mathrm{Re}\approx1900$ while another day at $\mathrm{Re}\approx2100$ for the same experiment.

Note that in the case of the Rayleigh-Taylor instability there is an assumed pertubation of the form:
$$e=e_0+\delta\left(t\right)\cos\left(\kappa x\right)$$
<s>This means that the theoretical treatment assumes the pertubations are already present, i.e. the pertubations do not grow spontaneously from a initially undisturbed uniform film.</s> *Rectification:* Even in a perfectly symmetric system the pertubation will occur because of surface tensile forces albeit much more slowly than in the case the system is perturbed by some external factor.

Comment: So what makes them? Shear Stress? Pressure (capillary)?
can you name those factors please?

Comment: @David2000 - I have modified my answer to make it more relevant

Comment: So, may I ask u another question? see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206205/stationary-waves-on-a-laminar-liquid-flow-near-collision-with-a-surface that you have answered. what does a surface and collision do that this happens?

Comment: @David2000 - considering the duplicate answers in that question, i am now less sure what you observe is indeed the Rayleigh-Plateau instability. Possibly you will have to start looking into impinging jets instead as suggested by [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190337) answer. sorry :)

Comment: so if you know about that, would you please edit your answer and tell me about that ?

Comment: @David2000 - unfortunately i do not know much about impinging jets but the answer i linked to should initially point you in the right direction. I will delete my answer to not confuse future readers